# Fullscreen window placement becomes fixed in expo workspace after switching monitors

Tags: unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, workspaces, fullscreen

I wonder if there is any way to loosen the fullscreen window placement rules under 14.04.  Rules are improved from 12.04 to 14.04 for conserving placement following a monitor switch (e.g., switching from a laptop display to an external monitor, with expo and a 3x3 workspace).  Under ubuntu 12.04, the position of fullscreen windows in the expo workspace often got mixed up randomly.

Although the situation improved under 14.04 (where fullscreen positions now are conserved between monitor switches), the fullscreen windows can't be repositioned by drag and drop in expo (they simply fall back into their original position and so hide any windows that may be underneath them).  Resizing a window in order to reposition it in the workspace seems a bit kludgy.